# Update ListView every second with Handler not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-sms

In my application where the app receives a new sms message, I want the listview to update it it immediately with the new message shown in the listview. I tried using the example code of the broadcast receiver code but it didn't work, so I'm now trying to use a timer to update the listview every second and show the latest message received but this isn't working either.

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        inboxArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        ((BaseAdapter)inboxmessages.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                        handler.postDelayed(this,  1000 );

                    }
                }, 1000);

        return view;
```

Original attempt of using BroadcastReceiver to update listview when new SMS message recieved.

**SmSBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    // https://javapapers.com/android/android-receive-sms-tutorial/
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null)
        {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++)
            {
                // Get sms message
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                // Get content and number
                String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                // Create display message
                smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";

                // Add it to the list
                CommandsFragment inst = CommandsFragment.instance();
                inst.updateList(smsMessageStr);
            }
            CommandsFragment inst = CommandsFragment.instance();
            inst.updateList(smsMessageStr);
        }
    }
}
```

**CommandsFragment.java**

```
 public static CommandsFragment instance()
        {
            return inst;
        }


        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            inst = this;
        }


        public static CommandsFragment newInstance()
        {
            CommandsFragment fragment = new CommandsFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

 public void updateList(final String smsMessage)
    {
        inboxArrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
        inboxArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: How about adding logging to see if your handler ever runs? Also, you might want to fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Get the Receiver working instead.

Comment: I can verify that the handler is running because I was using a Toast to display an output every second

Comment: Put the listview update code in a method, and call that method from broadcast receiver's `onReceive`. It would definitely work. Also check the code for whether you are updating the list view properly.

Comment: I just updated the question with my code of my attempt of the broadcast receiver code.

Comment: are you sure that there is some update in the data set?

Comment: Use `@override` for onReceive.

Comment: Yes there is an update in the dataset because when I change screens, the listview will then updated with the latest sms message received

Comment: I put in @override for onReceive in the SmsBroadcastReceiver.java, still didn't update the listview when the new SMS was received

Comment: where do you register your receiver

Comment: The receiver is in another class file called SmSBroadcastReceiver.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the listview update code inside a method in the Activity where the listview belongs, and call that method from broadcast receiver's onReceive. It would definitely work. Also check the code for whether you are updating the list view properly.

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent intent) { // change the parameters depending upon your requirements

    // do something here with the sms received if necessary

    // then call the listview update method here        
   }

}
```

Comment: I already have this code in, have a look at the CommandsFragment.java code I've shown in bold. In the sample code I am getting the content of the sms and updating the listview

Comment: Did you try logging inside the method to check whether the call reaches the method?

Comment: I put a log tag inside the onReceive method and checked with my debug output in Android Studio, I don't think it's reaching it

Comment: Then how do you say you received the sms? You receive the sms via receiver only!

Comment: Because when I go into another fragment or reopen the app again, the listview updates with the latest received sms

Answer (score 1):

Also to add to the answer don't forget to have this below in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
  </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SmsBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

This above also fixed the solution for me. Thanks for your help guys.